# How do I export an outline of my UV map so that I can paint a texture in an external editor?

Tags: uv

I'd like to edit a JPG texture in an external image editor. To do this accurately, I'd like to export an image showing the outline of my UV map, that I can trace over in the external editor. I'm using Blender 2.73, the mesh is unwrapped, I'm looking at it in the UV editor.